# Is this mod comment adhering to CoC?

Tags: discussion, support, code-of-conduct

In the question [Using courtesy and respect at GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/using-courtesy-and-respect-at-gis-se) the code of conduct is referenced. Reading them, about how you should be "patient and welcoming" and "Be clear and constructive when giving feedback" I cannot help to think that was not the case when receiving the following comment, before closing my question. (Note that I did not at any point have two active threads at one time).

> Thanks for reposting your question as it saved me finding your other one, reopening it and closing it as a duplicate

Is this clear and constructive, as well as patient or welcoming, or is it rather sarcastic? I get that this is a thankless job, but I dont understand why you would take your time to write such a comment as I do not think it fosters "a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect.".

My initial reaction was wanting to leave this community and don't come back. I can handle to have my questions closed (I am active in other stackexchange communities) however I really do not understand why you would take your time to write that rather than to be "clear and constructive when giving feedback". I obviously wanted help for my question, and I wished to adhere to the rules here.

Reference to the comment: [Implementation of an algorithm for finding the shortest path around obstacles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445229/implementation-of-an-algorithm-for-finding-the-shortest-path-around-obstacles)

Note: this is not a discussion on the question and mod activity in itself, but how that comment is in line with what is discussed in [Using courtesy and respect at GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/using-courtesy-and-respect-at-gis-se) and more specifically in the code of conduct.

Answer (score 2):

The Q&A on [Using courtesy and respect at GIS SE?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/using-courtesy-and-respect-at-gis-se) far pre-dates the Code of Conduct, and maybe even its predecessor which was the Be Nice policy.

I agree that the comment you cited appears to have a sarcastic tone.  However, when deciding whether something is unacceptable, rather than just unexpected, within the [Code of Conduct](https://gis.stackexchange.com/conduct) I use the section titled **Unacceptable Behavior**.  I think that comment is one that I would not write personally, and one that I would delete if I came across it organically.  However, it does not quite reach the level that I think warrants an "It's unfriendly or unkind" flag.

Answer (score -2):

I was gently pointing out that you had already transgressed by reposting a new question rather than fixing the [one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445132/finding-the-distance-between-two-points-at-sea-avoiding-land) that had already been asked and closed by the community. Normally, I would have found that one and closed the [new one](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/445229/seeking-algorithm-for-finding-shortest-path-around-obstacles) by marking it a duplicate.

In general, we the moderators and the system take a dim view of people attempting to game the system by posting new questions that are thinly edited version of a question that is already been closed for good reasons. I was particularly aware of your previous question as you had flagged it closure for moderator attention as you didn't like the fact you had been asked to show some sign of a good faith attempt to solve the problem. This is not a site to ask for people to do your "homework". So I had already spent a good chunk of my limited free time for moderation on your problems, be grateful I bothered to do a search and left a comment - I could have just nuked the question and moved on.

Comment: Saying "Thanks for reposting your question (... so that I could close it as duplicate)" is not "gently pointing out" when you blame the user for transgression. It is passive aggression.
From what is presented on this page right now, it looks like the user was harassed. It would be nice if the missing context was added so that the community can see what previous behavior of them might have triggered this.

Comment: @bugmenot123 What do you mean by harassment?

Comment: I don't enjoy closing questions, it is a pain in the ass and eats in to my limited time for fun.

Comment: @bugmenot123 It's sarcastic, sure. But I don't think one sarcastic statement crosses the line into harassment. He didn't torment or injure the OP with the sarcasm. But now, I might be getting into a matter of opinion. If Ian was repeatedly doing this, to point of a pattern, I'd be more likely see it as harassment. Maybe it wasn't a great way to write it, but if he had phrased it differently, it's a valid point. What the OP did is frowned upon.